# Measure default memory usage for next.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, pm2

I need to solve a problem in the memory usage of a next.js application.

To check default memory usage (Memory usage without any user) of a express.js RESTapi we could do this.

Server app via pm2
Check the memory status.

[image]

Now we are certain that this app could take 25mb in memory to run.

How could I check the same thing for a next.js application?
We could use `npm run dev` and `npm run start` commands to locally serve the production build. But how could we check the default memory usage for this as I did in pm2?

Answer (score 2):

You can monitor any npm script by using `--`:

```
pm2 start npm -- start
```

You could also monitor `npm run dev` by using:

```
pm2 start npm -- run dev
```

You can also pass a `--name` param to change the default name:

```
pm2 start --name my-app-dev npm -- run dev
```

`my-app-dev` will appear under the `name` column (e. g. when running `pm2 list`).

You can learn more in the [PM2 official documentation](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/quick-start/).